# Use a T-bar as a snowboarder without pain

Tags: winter, comfort, sports

This question got more attention (answers) on Sports, so [please respond here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/8637/use-a-t-bar-as-a-snowboarder-without-pain).

I'd describe myself as a rather experienced snowboarder respectively T-bar rider. I used to fall out the T-bar when I was a beginner. So now, riding the T-bar to the top isn't a problem at all. I'm having a problem with the **pain** I get **in** my **inner thigh**. If it's one T-bar a day it's not bad at all. But if 90% of lifts are T-bars and I'm riding a *whole week* in the same resort, the pain in the evenings is **tremendous**.

I used to ride ski before riding snowboard, and as a skier the T-bars aren't a problem. They just pull at your butt and it won't hurt - even after a week.

- I thought about placing a small cushion at my inner thigh but I'm worried, that it will restrict me while riding down the hills.
- Pulling with my arms only temporarily decreases the pressure on my thigh.

I hope there's a hacky solution to prevent the pain in my inner thigh which hopefully won't restrict my leg in movement while riding my snowboard.

Comment: It's probably stupid and dangerous to try, but I'll throw it in anyway - what about using some kind of climbing harness with a special rope to attach to the bar?

Comment: @MaxD At first this doesn't seem that bad. But you would have to modify the climbing harness, since the carbine usually sits in the front. Standing on a snowboard sideways, it would pull from the side. Thinking about it, this could actually be a niche market. Creative Thinking! +1

Comment: I think you should of asked in sports.

Comment: @Jon It would certainly increase the chance of getting an useful answer. Should I just ask the same question there or is there any way to move this question?

Comment: post it there delete it here, I do not know the process for migration, I believe it is the function of moderators and we may not have any yet.

Comment: can you ride it like a skier by taking your feet out of the bindings? Sort of ride the snowboard up the hill like a mono-ski? You'd likely want a tether so you don't loose the board if you wipe.

Comment: @DA. Would be possible, 'cause I already got a tether. But it would cost me more time before and after every lift to put out/in my front foot of the binding. Also, if the track of the lift isn't perfectly even, I wouldn't be able to compensate bumps.

Comment: Maybe it's been invented already, but I'm now envisioning a binding system that let's you easily rotate each foot into a perpendicular angle so you can use the board on a t-bar like you would a slalom water ski. Granted, the 't-bar' demographic is likely a narrow one. FYI, perhaps this would be better asked on Sports.se?

Comment: @DA. This sounds like a brilliant idea. I don't know if something like this already exists. If it does, I haven't heard of it. I actually did ask this on Sports. Check the bottom line.

Comment: Hmm...I'm OFF TO THE PATENT OFFICE!

Comment: why dont you just hold the t bar with your arms?

Comment: @celeriko Please check this question in Sports (link in bottom line) and the video posted as answer there. It states that's the wrong way to do it. Also I'm not hercules and 10min rides going >50% uphill is simply not possible by holding the t-bar with your hands/arms.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, I would just take my scarf, wrap it once around it, so when I sit on it I won't lose it but I could take it away easily, and then use the rest as u cushion.

It's not the best solution, but it was the easiest for me.